# YouTube videoId get from input api

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying out the YouTube API, and i'm stuck on to get the videoId by entering a URL in a text input.

This is the code;

```
var player;
var $input = $('#input-field');
var $messageForm = $('#input-form');
$messageForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log ($input.val());
    $input.val('');
});
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {

      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: $input.val(), // The video must be loaded based on $input.val()
      events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        onError: onPlayerError
      },
                playerVars: {
                    enablejsapi: 1,
                    controls: 0,
                    disablekb: 1,
                    fs: 0,
                    iv_load_policy: 3,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    rel: 0,
                    showinfo: 0
                }

    });
  }
```

im new and learning javascript so be easy on me ..

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no syntax errors, but it won't produce the desired result. The function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is executed only oat the time YouTube's API library is loaded, and I'm guessing that you don't have anything in `input-field` at that time. But there's no provision to have the player watch and load a video dynamically, so you'll have to build one yourself. For example, you could leverage your submit button and utilize YT's loadVideoById method, like this:

```
$messageForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (typeof player !== "undefined") {
       player.loadVideoById($(input.val()));
    }
});
```